# Comparison of Cloud Services

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting, game-development

I am trying to find a comparison of cloud services and platforms offered today. Is there any research article or something similar that could give me the numbers? Not concerned about the price, but about parameters like, latency, responsiveness etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from an abstract that may meet your needs for a comparison of cloud service performance.

Performance and Cost Assessment of Cloud Services:
“Using a suite of cloud testing applications we conducted in-depth empirical evaluations of a variety of real cloud infrastructures, including Google App Engine, Amazon EC2 and Microsoft Azure. The insights from these experimental evaluations, and other public/published data, were combined with the modeling technology to predict the resource requirements in terms of cost, application performance, and limitations of a realistic application for different deployment scenarios”.

The following IEEE links are related to this topic:
Performance Evaluation of Cloud Computing Offerings - [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5359493)

SMICloud: A Framework for Comparing and Ranking Cloud Services - [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6123500)

Performance and Cost Assessment of Cloud Services - http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-19394-1_5?LI=true